# Use a Live Card as a Shortcut to my application

Tags: google-glass, google-gdk

I have an application that my user would frequently have to access quickly and dismiss.

I wanted to allow the user be able to sticky my app as a live card but with only the overhead of a lower frequency card. I want to create a bookmark/shortcut to allow the user to launch and use my activity and then able to quit normally.

When I use high frequency cards they make my application hang and freeze. Is there a better way to accomplish this?

Also is this advisable as a UX/UI design standpoint?

Answer (score 4):

Without more context on what your application does, it's hard to know but I'm hesitant to say this is a good way to go about it.

If it's just as a pure shortcut, it's probably a bad idea. Glass already has the "ok glass" menu paradigm which is supported by both touch and voice input, while a card would only be supported by touch. Further, a bunch of live cards as shortcuts probably doesn't scale well if the user has a number of applications which do that.

On the other hand, if your application shows information on the live card that the user would want to see on a regular basis (think Google now cards, etc) then this might be a good idea depending on how it's executed.

Again, it's hard to know without more context. Glass is a different paradigm than phones or desktops so be careful when importing concepts from those other interaction paradigms.